# adding a custom subclass of JSplitPane in SwingBuilder using container() causes IllegalArgumentException

Tags: groovy, swingbuilder

I'm new to groovy and griffon and currently playing around a little bit with SwingBuilder. I would like to add a subclass of JSplitPane (which uses a thin divider as described at http://www.formdev.com/blog/swing-tip-jsplitpane-with-zero-size-divider/).

Below you can find the view definition script. I've used a container()-Element to add my Splitpane-subclass. When I start my application, I get an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException. Any ideas, how to fix this?

---

### The view:

```
frame(id:"frame",
 title: 'The new database explorer implemented with groovy/griffon',
 size: [600, 400],
 locationByPlatform:true,
 iconImage: imageIcon('/griffon-icon-48x48.png').image,
 iconImages: [imageIcon('/griffon-icon-48x48.png').image,
              imageIcon('/griffon-icon-32x32.png').image,
              imageIcon('/griffon-icon-16x16.png').image]) {

   panel (id:'mainPanel',
           opaque:false) {
       borderLayout()
       toolBar(id:'toolBar',
               constraints:NORTH,
               floatable:false,
               opaque: false,
               preferredSize: new Dimension(200,50)) {
           hglue()
           textField(id:'search', "clientPropertyJTextField.variant":"search",
                   maximumSize: new Dimension(150,35),
                   preferredSize: new Dimension(150,35))
       }
       panel(id: 'centerPanel',
               constraints: CENTER,
               opaque: true,
               background: new Color(238, 238, 238)) {
           borderLayout()
           container (new SplitPaneWithThinDivider(),
                      id:'mainSplitPane',
                      constraints: CENTER,
                      dividerLocation: 150
                      ) {
               scrollPane(id:'treeScroller', border:null) {
                   tree(id:'explorerTree',
                           rootVisible: false)
               }
               scrollPane(border:null) {
                   textArea()
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

---

### The exception:

```
2012-03-15 06:45:01,778 [AWT-EventQueue-0] ERROR org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder - An error occurred while building at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView@59c87031
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: null
    at java_awt_Container$add.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7_closure8.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:54)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7_closure8.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:49)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:47)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:31)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:167)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView.run(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:23)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:151)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:155)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)
2012-03-15 06:45:01,781 [main] ERROR griffon.util.GriffonExceptionHandler - Uncaught Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: null
    at griffon.swing.SwingUIThreadHandler.executeSync(SwingUIThreadHandler.java:46)
    at griffon.core.UIThreadManager.executeSync(UIThreadManager.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup.buildScriptMember(AbstractMVCGroup.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultMVCGroupManager.initializeMembers(DefaultMVCGroupManager.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultMVCGroupManager.buildMVCGroup(DefaultMVCGroupManager.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroupManager.createMVCGroup(AbstractMVCGroupManager.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroupManager.createMVCGroup(AbstractMVCGroupManager.java:186)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractGriffonApplication.createMVCGroup(AbstractGriffonApplication.java:499)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractGriffonApplication.startup(AbstractGriffonApplication.java:313)
    at griffon.swing.AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.realize(AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.java:78)
    at griffon.swing.AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.run(AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.java:132)
    at griffon.swing.SwingApplication.main(SwingApplication.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: unknown constraint: null
    at java_awt_Container$add.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7_closure8.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:54)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7_closure8.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:49)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4_closure7.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:47)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2_closure4.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:140)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:31)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView$_run_closure2.doCall(ExplorerFrameView.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:96)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.this$3$invokeFactoryMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass$this$3$invokeFactoryMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:167)
    at at.rehdie.dbexp.main.ExplorerFrameView.run(ExplorerFrameView.groovy:23)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberInterceptorMetaClass.invokeMethod(UberInterceptorMetaClass.groovy:151)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.builder.UberBuilder.build(UberBuilder.groovy:155)
    at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractMVCGroup$1.run(AbstractMVCGroup.java:129)
```

Answer (score 2):

A wild, untested guess, but does:

```
       widget( new SplitPaneWithThinDivider(),
               id:'mainSplitPane',
               constraints: CENTER,
               dividerLocation: 150,
               leftComponent: scrollPane(id:'treeScroller', border:null) {
                 tree(id:'explorerTree', rootVisible: false )
               },
               rightComponent: scrollPane(border:null) {
                 textArea()
               } )
```

Work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the code with Griffon 0.9.5-rc2, but used application() instead of frame(), and splitPane() as I don't have access to the custom SplitPaneWithThinDivider component and it works. I presume ExplorerFrameView belongs to a secondary MVC group. Have you tried using application() instead of frame() ?

You can have as many application() nodes per Views as this node has pretty much the same behavior as frame() but it knows how to deal with applets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, Tim's version works perfectly. I've also tried the following:

```
splitPane (new SplitPaneWithThinDivider(),
           id:'mainSplitPane',
           constraints: CENTER,
           dividerLocation: 150,
           "clientPropertyQuaqua.Tree.style": "sideBar",
           border: null) {

   scrollPane(id:'treeScroller', border:null) {
       tree(id:'explorerTree',
            rootVisible: false)
   },           
   scrollPane(border:null) {
       textArea()
   }           
}
```

But this way the left component of the splitpane was always the default "Left button" (the same was true, when I used `new JSplitPane()` instead of `new SplitPaneWithThinDivider()`).

When I changed it to

```
splitPane (new SplitPaneWithThinDivider(),
           id:'mainSplitPane',
           constraints: CENTER,
           dividerLocation: 150,
           "clientPropertyQuaqua.Tree.style": "sideBar",
           border: null) {

   scrollPane(id:'treeScroller', border:null) {
       tree(id:'explorerTree',
            rootVisible: false)
   },           
   scrollPane(border:null) {
       textArea()
   }           
}
bean(mainSplitPane, leftComponent: treeScroller)
```

it worked.